# why get the attributes of the parent class

Tags: java

```
public class Index2 extends Test {
    public String name = "a";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Index2().method();
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println(this.name);
        super.method();
    }

}

class Test {

    public String name = "b";

    public void method() {
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
}
```

console:

```
com.Index2@15db9742
a
com.Index2@15db9742
b
```

2 println(this) have same object(com.Index2@15db9742) where not a a?
why the object is same(com.Index2@15db9742) but 1st println get "a" and 2nd println get "b"

and why 2nd 'this' is (com.Index2@15db9742) not (com.Test@xxxxxxx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the super.method() in child class you get the parent classes (Test class) vars, that does not mean you have an instance of it. You have initiate Index2 so the object name is the same.
View the usage of [ Test ttt=new Test(); ] bellow.

```
public class Index2 extends Test {
public String name = "a";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Index2().method();
}
Test ttt=new Test();
public void method() {
    System.out.println(this);
    System.out.println(this.name);
    super.method();
    ttt.method();
}}
```

To resolve with setter, basically you can use like below

```
public class Index2 extends Test {

public static String name = "a";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Index2().method(name);
}

public void method(String name) {
    System.out.println("This is a");
    System.out.println(this);
    System.out.println(this.name);
    super.method(this.name);
}}    
class Test {
public String name = "b";

public void method(String nameVar) {
    this.name=nameVar;
    System.out.println("This is b");
    System.out.println(this);
    System.out.println(this.name);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the subclass doesn't *overwrite* the attribute `name`, it *shadows* it. `Test.name` still exists, it's just no longer directly accessible from within `Index2`.

When you call `super.method()`, the program exits the class `Index2` and goes back to `Test`. Since `Index2.name` is no longer in scope (no longer shadowing `Test.name`), `test.name` is the one that gets used.

It's the same object - as an instance of `Index2`, the object contains both an `Index2.name` and a `Test.name`, the latter of which is only accessible when calling through the superclass method.

If you want to circumvent this behavior - if you want `Test.method()` to print `"a"` instead of `"b"`, in this case - then use a getter method. Java has different rules for runtime method resolution than it does for variable name resolution, and will use the version of the method that the subclass implements (in this case `Index2`), which would return `Index2.name`.

Comment: think you for answer and help!! but! in Test.method() use println(this), i get a "com.Index2@15db9742"!  if goes back to Test, in Test.method() this need to be "com.Test@xxxxxxx"?

Comment: It's still the same `this`, but the difference is that `Index2.method()` accesses `Index2.name`, while `Test.method()` accesses `Test.name`, and the object has both of them.

Comment: got it ! ty! but why~~~~~!? is there any way to prove it? couse i think it may be shoud  like  "com.Index2.super@15db9742"~~ or  "com.Test@xxxxxxx"! i try to use jdb to find that! but not success

Comment: getter() works!i will continue to pay attention to this issue! diff is getter() return `this.name`, method just use this.name! when i just write a getter methon in Test,it still get 'b', should write a getter methon in Index2 can get 'a'!